# <td ng-repeat="x in names |orderBy:'-Hindi' | limitTo:1"> {{x.name}} The marks should update if a user edits any single slot of data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to change the code that every time a user  edits the marks in English or Hindi and then the highest Hindi and/or English marks are updated accordingly

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)
{
$scope.names = [
        {name:'Priya',age:'19',gender:'Female',English:x[0], Hindi:x[1]},
        ....
        ....
        {name:'Dev', age:'18' ,gender:'Male',English:x[2] ,Hindi:x[3]},
           ];

$scope.sum = function(list) 
    {
        var total=0;
        angular.forEach(list , function(x){
        total+= x[];
    });
    return total;
}
});
```

**HTML CODE**
This is the code I use currently for displaying the highest marks

```
<tr ng-repeat ="x in names | orderBy:'sortColumn'">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.age}}</td>
        <td>{{x.gender}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.English"></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.Hindi"></td>
        <td ng-bind="avg=(x.English+x.Hindi)/2">{{avg}}</td>
        <td>
            <button><a href="" ng-click="delete(x)">Delete</a></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table ng-model="sum">
    <tr><td>The total is: <input value="{{sum(x)}}"></td></tr>

  **<tr><td>THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY HIGHEST MARKS IN ENGLISH</td></tr>**
  **<tr><td>**<td ng-repeat="x in names |orderBy:'-Hindi' | limitTo:1"> {{x.name}}THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY HIGHEST MARKS IN HINDI</td></tr>**


</table>
```

Comment: What is this for? `English:x[0]`

Comment: I made an array x with its elements produced through a random number generator.

Comment: @TanayChoudhary what was the reason you unaccepted the answer? It did not help you?

Comment: @Pradeepb my bad, I am new to stack overflow. I accepted it again. Could you please help me with another issue. The edited problem. Thanks again sir.

Comment: You just want to display the highest marks right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `watch` on array like below:

```
$scope.total = 0

$scope.$watch('names', function(newVal) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(newVal, function(x) {
      total += parseInt(x.English) + parseInt(x.Hindi);
    });
    $scope.total = total
}, true);
```

and in template replace `{{sum(x)}}` with `{{total}}`.

Check working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32369/)